# Who to tell I'm leaving the company? And how much advanced notice?

Tags: quitting

I am leaving my company for a more attractive role at a different company. Should I tell my current manager who's moving to a new role in July or wait for his replacement to break the news to?

A little background. I've worked in this HR role for 4 months now after transferring from a different front office where I've worked for 3 years. He's already lost 2 other team members with long tenures in the last 4 months before me and had to replace them (I don't know how long it took him).

As is, I found out this manager is leaving for a different role in a different branch of our company. He expects to finish his transition by early July. I landed a job with a different company and negotiated a later start date (early August) so that I can give the manager time to find a replacement and see ongoing projects 3/4 through to help transition. Should I tell him this? And should I tell him now? How much notice should I give?

Comment: Give the amount of notice that is contractually required or is the norm in your country. Give it to your immediate boss at the time you give notice. It down;e matter if he is moving on to something else or if it is his first day.

Comment: What country is this in? Typically, you need to provide the greater of the state/province mandated minimum (typically documented in some sort of government-provided employment standards document) or what is stipulated in your employment agreement. If you work in an at-will employment state in the US, you may not be required to provide notice: just your resignation is sufficient.

Comment: This question is asked over and over.  Always only give notice at the **last possible minute**, under whatever contract or legal obligations you have.  Never tell anyone, early, that you're leaving.

Comment: I am mildly worried that you are working in a HR role but don't know how much notice you should give.

Answer (score 10):

Give notice to you current supervisor, as required by your contract.  That's how you officially quit your job.  If your manager is also leaving (and before you yourself would be gone) then it might also be a wise idea to let your *new* manager know, when he or she begins, that you've already given notice and will be leaving on Date X.  However, that "notice" is mainly a courtesy, so the new guy knows what's what.

Answer (score 2):

Legally you are supposed to hand in your resignation to the person you  "report to" as per contract.

And it is ideal to include the date of your last day at work in your resignation letter. (Just to put it out there). If you putting a date on paper, it cannot be less than whats required of you as per contract.

However if you wish to quit early, then you have to come at a mutual consensus with your Manager and agree on a date.

If you have already handed your resignation, and your Manager changes, then technically he/she should be well aware of your situation already. That will be a task in the handover of your old manager.

In the worst case, the new manager is not aware, you will have to let them know about it. Having said that, even if you dont tell them, legally you wont get into trouble because you already handed your resignation once.

Comment: If you gave notice to your old manager, the old manager left but didn't do his job properly and pass this information on to anyone, and you leave at the end of your notice period as a complete surprise to your new manager and everyone else, you may be legally right, but that doesn't mean there won't be trouble. So you'd better tell the new manager immediately, and also tell HR yourself that you gave notice. There might be no record of your resignation.

Comment: Legally where? Where I live, I think you are giving your notice to the whole company, the juridical person with which you have a contract. Typically you would inform your manager or HR formally or informally but that's not a legal requirement.